Regarding Theorem 3.23 in Folland
I'm reading the section on functions of bounded variation in Folland's real analysis text. The first theorem of the section deals with two basic properties of increasing functions, which I'm stuck on.
There are some theorems referenced in the proof of the theorem below, which I assume the reader is familiar with. However, I think my questions only requires skimming through the proof and not knowing every single detail.
Theorem and proof

3.23 Theorem Let $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be increasing and let $G(x)=F(x+)$.
a. The set of points at which $F$ is discontinuous is countable.
b. $F$ and $G$ are differentiable a.e., and $F'=G'$ a.e.


Proof. Since $F$ is increasing, the intervals $(F(x-),F(x+))$ $(x\in\mathbb R)$ are disjoint and for $|x|<N$ they lie in the interval $(F(-N),F(N))$. Hence $$\sum_{|x|<N}[F(x+)-F(x-)]\leq F(N)-F(-N)<\infty,$$which implies that $\{x\in(-N,N):F(x+)\neq F(x-)\}$ is countable. As this is true for all $N$, (a) is proved.
Next, we observe that $G$ is increasing and right continuous, and $G=F$ except perhaps where $F$ is discontinuous. Moreover, $$G(x+h)-G(x)=\begin{cases} \mu_G((x,x+h])&\text{if }h>0,\\ -\mu_G((x+h,x])&\text{if }h<0,\end{cases}$$and the families $\{(x-r,x]\}$ and $\{(x,x+r]\}$ shrink nicely to $x$ as $r=|h|\to 0$. Thus, an application of Theorem 3.22 to the measure $\mu_G$ (which is regular by Theorem 1.18) shows that $G'(x)$ exists for a.e. $x$. To complete the proof, it remains to show that if $H=G-F$, then $H'$ exists and equals zero a.e.
Let $\{x_j\}$ be an enumeration of the points at which $H\neq 0$. Then $H(x_j)>0$, and as above we have $\sum_{\{j:|x_j|<N\}}H(x_j)<\infty$ for any $N$. Let $\delta_j$ be the point mass at $x_j$ and $\mu=\sum_j H(x_j)\delta_j$. Then $\mu$ is finite on compact sets by the preceding sentence, and hence $\mu$ is regular by Theorems 1.16 and 1.18; also $\mu\perp m$ since $m(E)=\mu(E^c)=0$ where $E=\{x_j\}_1^\infty$. But then $$\left|\frac{H(x+h)-H(x)}{h}\right|\leq\frac{H(x+h)+H(x)}{|h|}\leq 4\frac{\mu\big((x-2|h|,x+2|h|)\big)}{4|h|},$$which tends to zero as $h\to0$ for a.e. $x$, by Theorem 3.22. Thus $H'=0$ a.e., and we are done.


Questions



Folland claims $\{(x,x+r]\}$ shrinks nicely to $x$. According to the definition of "shrink nicely", they have to

$E_r\subset B(r,x)$ for each $r$,

there is a constant $\alpha>0$, independent of $r$, such that $m(E_r)>\alpha m(B(r,x))$.


But $E_r=(x,x+r]$ is not a subset of $B(r,x)=(x-r,x+r)$, or?
2.
Can someone explain how $\sum_{\{j:|x_j|<N\}}H(x_j)<\infty$? I just don't understand how it follows as in the case of $\sum_{|x|<N}[F(x+)-F(x-)]<\infty$.
3.
Does the author show $F$ is differentiable?

For your "question 1", just change the indexing: make $E_r=(x, x +\frac{r}{2}] $. Then, $E_r = (x, x +\frac{r}{2}] \subset (x-r,x+r) = B(r,x)$ for each $r$, and $m(E_r)= \frac{r}{2} > \frac{1}{8} (2r)=\frac{1}{8} m(B(r,x))$ independent of $r$. Take $\alpha = \frac{1}{8}$.

@Ramiro Thank you, that helped. I think I understand the rest of my questions. However, a new question has come up. Why does the author state $\mu\perp m$ and why does the term $4\frac{\mu\big((x-2|h|,x+2|h|)\big)}{4|h|}$ tend to $0$? Theorem 3.22 requires only that $\mu$ be regular.

For your "question 2", note that
$$\sum_{|x|<N} H(x) = \sum_{|x|<N}[G(x)-F(x)] =\sum_{|x|<N}[F(x+)-F(x)] \leq \sum_{|x|<N}[F(x+)-F(x-)] \leq \\leq F(N)-F(-N)<\infty$$

Ah, great! Thanks!

Let $X= {x_j: j}$. So, $X$ is a countable set and, since $\mu=\sum_j H(x_j)\delta_j$ (where $\delta_j$ be the point mass at $x_j$), we have $m(X) =0$ and $\mu(\Bbb R \setminus X) =0$. It means $\mu \perp m$.

@Ramiro Indeed, but what's the relevance of $\mu\perp m$ for the rest of the proof? Does it imply $4\frac{\mu\big((x-2|h|,x+2|h|)\big)}{4|h|}$ tending to $0$ as $h\to 0$?

You must apply Theorem 3.22.  Since $\mu \perp m$, we have $\mu = \mu + 0 m$ as $\mu$ Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym representation. So by Theorem 3.22, for $m$-almost every $x \in \Bbb R$,
$$ \lim_{|h| \to 0} \frac{\mu\big((x-2|h|,x+2|h|)\big)}{4|h|} =\lim_{|h| \to 0}  \frac{\mu\big((x-2|h|,x+2|h|)\big)}{m\big((x-2|h|,x+2|h|)\big)}=0$$
